# Where is the RpcEnv instance in, Driver, Master or Worker?

Tags: apache-spark, rpc

Where is the `RpcEnv` instance in, and how every components get the corresponding `rpcEnv` instance? How do the components make connection to each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RpcEnv` is an **RPC Environment** that is created separately for every component in Spark and is used to exchange messages between each other for remote communication.

Spark creates the RPC environments for the driver and executors (by executing [SparkEnv. createDriverEnv](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkEnv.scala#L158) and [SparkEnv.createExecutorEnv](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkEnv.scala#L193) methods, respectively).

`SparkEnv.createDriverEnv` is used exclusively when `SparkContext` [is created for the driver](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.scala#L432):

```
_env = createSparkEnv(_conf, isLocal, listenerBus)
```

You can create a RPC Environment using `RpcEnv.create` factory methods yourself (as do ExecutorBackends, e.g. [CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/executor/CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala#L222)):

```
val env = SparkEnv.createExecutorEnv(
    driverConf, executorId, hostname, cores, cfg.ioEncryptionKey, isLocal = false)
```

---

Separate `RpcEnv`s are also created for [standalone Master](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/master/Master.scala#L1030) and [workers](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/worker/Worker.scala#L743).

---

> How do the components make connection to each other?

No much magic here :) The driver for a Spark application and the standalone Master for a Spark Standalone cluster are created first and they have no dependency on other components.

When the driver of a Spark application starts, it requests resources (in the form of resource containers from a cluster manager) with the command to launch executors (that differs per cluster manager). In the launch command, there are connection details (i.e. host and port) of the driver's RpcEndpoint.

See how it works with Hadoop YARN in [Client](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/resource-managers/yarn/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/yarn/Client.scala#L801).

It is a similar process with standalone Workers with the difference that the administrator has to specify the master's URL at command line.

```
$ ./sbin/start-slave.sh
Usage: ./sbin/start-slave.sh [options] <master>

Master must be a URL of the form spark://hostname:port

Options:
  -c CORES, --cores CORES  Number of cores to use
  -m MEM, --memory MEM     Amount of memory to use (e.g. 1000M, 2G)
  -d DIR, --work-dir DIR   Directory to run apps in (default: SPARK_HOME/work)
  -i HOST, --ip IP         Hostname to listen on (deprecated, please use --host or -h)
  -h HOST, --host HOST     Hostname to listen on
  -p PORT, --port PORT     Port to listen on (default: random)
  --webui-port PORT        Port for web UI (default: 8081)
  --properties-file FILE   Path to a custom Spark properties file.
                           Default is conf/spark-defaults.conf.
```

Comment: As every component has its own rpcEnv, how the components make connection？If the driver register as a RpcEndpoint in driver`s rpcEnv, and workers have anther rpcEnv, can these rpcEnv make connection?